# Get database record based on id

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Greeting,
I have an website that display products everything okay until now but i want the current user that have logged in to get his/ her data only, eg. if the user has id=1 its will get all products will id=1 (i have foreign key constrain between the two tables) i am using very simple controller that only get all products, i didn't find any solution at google.
i am using .NET CORE 3.0 with EntityFramework and SQL SERVER database
i am currently using JWT token that is stored inside local storage at web browser.

here is my ProductsController

```
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IAuthRepository _repo;
    private readonly DataContext _context;
    public ProductsController(DataContext context, IAuthRepository repo)
    {
        _context = context;
        _repo = repo;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AllProducts()
    {
        var All = await _context.Product.ToListAsync();
        return Ok(All);



    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should show us how do you store the information about the _ID_ of the current user when they log in.

Comment: yes i am forget , i am using token stored in the local storage of the website

Comment: How to you send this token? Is it JWT? Generally where is your authentication mechanism for the project?

Comment: yes yes i am using  JWT

Answer (score 0):

below is the code to get userid from jwt token

```
var context = new HttpContextAccessor();
var principal = context.HttpContext.User;
if (null == principal)
        return null;
var id = principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

Then update your action method " AllProducts" to

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> AllProducts()
{
    var context = new HttpContextAccessor();
            var principal = context.HttpContext.User;
            if (null == principal)
                return null;
            var userid = principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

    var All = await _context.Product.where(p=>p.id==userid).ToListAsync();
    return Ok(All);
}
```